# Align to bottom of Div while maintaining resizing for accessibility

Tags: css

I've seen how to force a Div to the bottom of a containing Div with postion: absolute; and bottom: 0px; and how to force a containing Div to expand to accommodate a child Div, but I can't get them to work together. I'm trying to make a site that will be accessible to viewers who change font sizes in their browsers.

This code will force a Div to the bottom, but doesn't make the containing Div expand as neccesary. If I change .exhibit_text postion to relative, the containing Div expands, but bottom alignment is lost. (The text is coming from a database, so I don't know how long it will be or how big the user will have set their font size.)

```
<style type="text/css">
.exhibit {
    position: relative;
}
.exhibit_text {
    width: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
}
.exhibit_image {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 450px;
    background-color:#FF0;
}
hr {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
<hr />
<div class='exhibit'>
    <div class='exhibit_text'><p>Long text: Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="exhibit_image">
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class='exhibit'>
    <div class='exhibit_text'><p>Short text: Susan Low-Beer and Meryl McMaster expand our understanding of the genre. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="exhibit_image">
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your meaning of "expand", so i guessed that you want the divs of the container(DIV) to be at bottom and the container(DIV) may expand the height.

here's the code:

```
.exhibit > div{
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

try it:)

Comment: Great! That worked for once I applied it to both .exhibit_text and .exhibit_image, and removed all the other positioning instructions (float, bottom, poistion). Thx.

Comment: But oddly, I don't seem to be able to combine inline-tables with varying vertical-alignments... The reference above shows only one type of vertical-align per container div.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting rid of the width setting on the `exhibit_text`. I would instead set a `min-width: 380px` and set `width: auto`. This should meant that the div will expand to contain all the content that is held within it, as well as not go any smaller than 380px wide.

EDIT: I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve. I pasted your code into a JSFIDDLE, and at 25px font, it just wraps the text around. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzVJu/)

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and it still has the problem I was experiencing (though not describing well). The first div container is not increasing it's height to accommodate the oversized child div. If I change .exhibit_text postion to relative, the container resizes, but I lose the bottom alignment. Thx.